# Showing CSV-file in GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I created a PostGIS connection in QGIS and I added in a CSV-file.

I added this database into GeoServer but inside this, I don't have the CSV-file.

How can I add it as well?

---

So is it not possible visualize CSV in geoserver?

Comment: You need to provide examples of your actions, i.e. how you downloaded the file with the extension .CSV in Postgres/PostGIS database and so on...

Comment: is it a Postgres table or a CSV file?

Comment: I added a CSV file into Postgis conncection in Qgis

Comment: ... so there is no CSV involved. Drop that from your mind. Does your Postgres table contain a geometry field?

Comment: Strictly you don't visualize any data in GeoServer, you use GeoServer to provide data to be visualized elsewhere (using standard interfaces/APIs)

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer will only show you tables that have a geometry column in them.

Comment: So is not possible add CSV-file into Geoserver?

Comment: You would need to add the [gt-csv](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/unsupported/csv.html) plugin - but there isn't much point if it has no geometry